# Error with importing OVF file into Google Compute

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, ovf, ova

I am receiving this error when trying to import an ovf file into compute instances. I am using gcloud compute instances import vm-test --source-uri=gs://test.ovf --os=ubuntu-2004. But when it comes to the disk bootable on compute engine it fails because of package "ubuntu-repo.comverge.com".

```
[import-disk-4]: 2023-10-19T13:26:30Z Inspecting the image file...
[import-disk-1]: 2023-10-19T13:26:30Z Inspecting the image file...
[import-disk-2]: 2023-10-19T13:26:30Z Inspecting the image file...
[import-disk-3]: 2023-10-19T13:26:30Z Inspecting the image file...
[import-ovf]: 2023-10-19T13:33:45Z Importing boot Disk Image ...
[import-ovf]: 2023-10-19T13:33:45Z Inspecting the image file...
[import-ovf]: 2023-10-19T13:41:11Z Inspecting disk for OS and bootloader
[import-ovf]: 2023-10-19T13:42:24Z Inspection result=os_release:{cli_formatted:"ubuntu-2004" distro:"ubuntu" major_version:"20" minor_version:"04" architecture:X64 distro_id:UBUNTU} bios_bootable:true elapsed_time_ms:72531 os_count:1
[import-ovf]: 2023-10-19T13:42:41Z Making disk bootable on Google Compute Engine
[import-ovf]: 2023-10-19T13:50:23Z Cleaning up.
[import-ovf]: 2023-10-19T13:50:24Z step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-translate-translate-disk-16bpj": "TranslateFailed: error: E: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu-repo.comverge.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/more-itertools/python3-more-itertools_4.2.0-1build1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'ubuntu-repo.comverge.com'"
```

I was expecting to see a completed status of the ovf file imported into google compute engine